# Convert linq method syntax to query syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Not that it would be better, but I'm trying to get my head around turning the following method syntax to query syntax to see the difference.

```
long diskSpace = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"c:\")
                    .SelectMany(Directory.EnumerateFiles)
                    .Sum(fileSize => new FileInfo(fileSize).Length);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That query is mostly equivalent to:

```
long diskSpace = (from directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"c:\")
                  from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory)
                  select file)
                 .Sum(file => new FileInfo(file).Length);
```

(I've renamed `fileSize` to `file` to more accurately represent the meaning, btw.)

There's one *actual* difference in this case - we're creating a new delegate which calls `Directory.EnumerateFiles` rather than *directly* creating a delegate from the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` method group. In other words, it's one extra level of redirection - but this won't have any effect on the results and I'd be amazed if it had any *significant* performance impact.

Comment: Thanks, need to tune my mind more towards sql again, and practice the dual from syntax which would be the join.

Comment: Bart De Smet wrote a convenient translation [cheat sheet](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/30/c-3-0-query-expression-translation-cheat-sheet.aspx) to go between method and query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference.

The compiler translates query syntax aka LINQ, into these methods calls. Query syntax is just syntactic suguar. It's not magic.

Comment: Of course there is difference. It looks different. And that was his whole point :)

Comment: Under the hood it's the same, yes, but for coding as you can see there are big differences.

Comment: it might be easier to, or adventagous to go with the LINQ syntax. but the fact still remains that it is identical. something you typically don't think of when writing LINQ syntax is that you pull a lot of variables from an anonymous scope into your "expression" something that, without LINQ, is not possible. LINQ syntax is, however, typically more readable than a mesh of extension methods and temporary variables.

Comment: Aren't they both 'LINQ Syntax'?